# Plotting a Wavefunction

Tags: plotting, functions

I am trying to plot a wavefunction for a 1D Particle in a box. I attached my code below, when I run it, it shows a plot with no lines on it. I am new to mathematica, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
    a = 30
    f[x_] := Sqrt[2/a]*((3/5)*sin ((2*\[Pi]*x)/a) + (4/5)*(sin ((9*\[Pi]*x)/a)))
    Plot[f[x], {x, 0, a},AxesLabel->{"x","f(x"},PlotStyle->{Black,Dashed}]
```

I have attached an image of the output.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. All WL built-in functions start with an upper case letter. `sin` should be `Sin`. Arguments are enclosed in `[ ]` not `( )`. `Sin[...]`.

Comment: Hey Molly, this is a typical problem for beginners in _Mathematica_. Nothing to be ashamed of whatsoever. However, I vote to close this thread, because it is just  a syntax error and because this is our clean-up policy. Nothing personal. Your input is still welcome on this site. Have fun learning this new language!

Comment: And you really should: (1) get rid of all the unnecessary `*` signs for multiplication: `2 π x` is enough (while a space is needed between `π` and `x`, you do not need to insert a space between `2` and `π`; (2) remove superfluous parentheses, e.g., around the second `Sin` expression; and (3) put a semicolon after `a= 30` unless you have some special reason to create a separate outpu cell with `30` in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = 30;
f[x_] := Sqrt[2/a] (3/5 Sin[2 \[Pi] x/a] + 4/5 Sin [(9 \[Pi] x)/a])
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, a}, AxesLabel -> {x, "f(x)"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashed}]
```

[image: A wave function.]

Note that you forgot the closing `)` in the `AxesLabel` expression `f(x)`.

When you actually type the input, you may want to take advantage of the Mathematica front end by typing Esc `p` Esc (with the escape key) to create the symbol `π`, or at least use `Pi`; after all, `\[Pi]` is a lot to type when you don't need to do so. (Perhaps you did do that; good! If you copy that from a notebook and paste here, you will get `\[Pi]`.)